# Using args.length instead of nums.length

Tags: java, count, average, calculator, args

I need to calculate the number of integers in an arg as well as calculate the average. Currently my code is the following with the problem in bold.

```
int count = args.length;
    System.out.println(count);

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
        **sum += args[i];**
            **//  The operator += is undefined for the argument type(s) int, String**

    double average = ((double) sum) / args.length;


}
```

How do i make it so that the average is calculated using integers in args.length?

Comment: Check out the signature of main method. Its p.s.v.m(String args[]). That is, `args is an array of type String`. Hence the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your args variable is an array of Strings and you can't add directly a String to an int. Use this instead :

```
sum += Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
```

Moreover using a for each can make the code easier to read :

```
for(final String s:args) { 
    sum += Integer.parseInt(s); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `sum += Integer.parseInt(args[i]);`

Answer (score 1):

```
sum += args[i];
```

should be

```
sum += Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Command-Line arguments generally accepted as Strings.So you have to first converting it to number and use it like this

```
sum+=Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you get String from the `args` arguments when you enter those on the command line. You need to convert them to type `Integer`.

Use this,

```
sum += Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
```